# Magento- add new menu item inside the module

Tags: magento, module, magento-1.7

currently I want to add a new menu link on the menu tab, but can it be done without changing other module template, but just add inside my module? The reason I want to do like this is because I hope when I disable my module the menu link also will be gone.

page.xml(other module layout file )

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Header</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
```

referral.xml(my module)
???
What should I do?
[image]

topmenu.phtml

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
    <?php if($_menu): ?>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <ul id="nav">
            <?php $active = is_numeric(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'aboutus')) ? 'active' : ''; ?>
            <li class="level0 nav-2 last level-top <?php echo $active; ?>">
                <a class="level-top" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);?>aboutus">
                    <span>About Us</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
            <?php $active = is_numeric(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'redemption/store')) ? 'active' : ''; ?>
            <li class="level0 nav-2 last level-top <?php echo $active; ?>">
                <a class="level-top" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);?>redemption/store">
                    <span>Redemption Store</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a custom navigation to me, there's no way out of the box to add items to the main navigation (none category items anyway).

by default it will only show categories, so yours looks like it's probably hard coded into the template.

Having worked with a lot of modules and themes I would be VERY surprised if it's a custom theme with the added ability to add links through either XML config, or admin options.

can you post some code from your topmenu.phtml file for me and then I can adivse the best action for you.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to write Navigation class in your custom module that will extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` in that class is a function (`renderCategoriesMenuHtml`) that you need to override in your local navigation class.
but the problem is, in real time users mostly have different themes and they change classes etc this can conflict in design implementation.